# No email notification on custom discussion list

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, discussion-board, newsfeed, notifications

On my social profile, I've configured the newsfeed settings in order to receive all the emails, as follows :
[image]

When someone answers to a discussion I've created on the default Discussions list of a Community Site, I'm receiving email notifications. But when it's a custom Discussions list, no emails are sent.

Does anyone have an idea ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce your issue, it seems that it’s the default behavior which the email notification sends to the relevant user when someone replied to community discussion post in default Discussions list.

As an alternative, you can set alert in this custom discussion list through LIST->Alert Me->set alert in this list.

Comment: Thanks @Hellofiona_SPWX, that's what I think also, but I'm still looking for an official documentation.